# Strain gauge measurements with carrier frequency

Tags: amplifier, signal, frequency, measurement, strain-gage

In near future, I would need to do strain gauge measurements using HBMs instruments, the amplifier will be MX1615B.

In my case, the gauges will be placed near a 50Hz gearmotor and run with VFD.

As far as I understand, this can cause a lot of noise to measurements and when I discussed with HBM supplier he suggested me to use carrier frequency of 1200Hz.

With carrier frequency of 1200Hz the bandwidth will be 400Hz, and the supplier thought that would be enough.

Well, because I'm not from electronic background I tried to study the subject but still can't get my head around it.

[image]

[image]

- So how much data I'm able to transfer from my measurements?
- How do I know if it is enough for me?
- What does this 400Hz bandwidth with 1200Hz carrier frequency mean?

[image]

Comment: You will need to tell what the bandwidth of the vibration/load/whatever that you are trying to measure is?

Comment: Please, can you explain your question to me as I would be 5 years old?

Comment: Hmmm, what exactly are you trying to measure?